# MongoDB C# filter array object with array filter

Tags: c#, mongodb, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a array filed on model:

```
public IList<RelationModel> RawMaterials { get; set; }
```

```
public class RelationModel
{
    public int EntityID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and a array for `FilterDefinition`:

```
public IList<int> Materials { get; set; }
```

Now I want make filter for this tow array

```
var filter = Builders<model>
    .Filter
    .ElemMatch(m => m.RawMaterials, {EntityID cointains Materials});
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the root document model schema as below:

```cs
public class Model
{
    public IList<RelationModel> RawMaterials { get; set; }
}
```

`$elemMatch` is part of the right way to access the nested element. While you also need the `$in` operator to filter the `ID` of the `RelationModel` object within the `Materials` array.

In MongoDB .NET Driver syntax, it should be:

```cs
var filter = Builders<Model>.Filter.ElemMatch(m => m.RawMaterials, 
    Builders<RelationModel>.Filter.In(x => x.EntityID, Materials));
```

Comment: thanks sir, good

also i find this way:
var filter = Builders<Model>.Filter.ElemMatch(m => m.RawMaterials, x => Materials.Contains(x.EntityID));